# IE11: Object doesn't support property or method 'createEvent'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm having following code in an old application:

```
var MyClass = function() {
  this.writeBackDate = function() {
    var onchangeEvent = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    /* some other code */
  }
}
```

Which fails on Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17358. The error given is "Object doesn't support property or method 'createEvent'".

It works just fine in Google Chrome.
I have no idea, what the problem could be. I googled around an hour and haven't found any hints. I have removed every other error, to exclude consecutive faults...

We're having a `X-UA-Compatible IE=6` HTTP Response Header in IIS.

Comment: Get rid of the IE6 compatibility header. The `createEvent` method was not supported before IE9.

Comment: Depending on which version of IE you need to support, it might be a better option to use `addEventListener` ... but seeing your comaptibility header that might not be an option.

Comment: Also, `6` is not a supported value for the x-ua-compatible header.  You're most likely getting IE5 quirks mode.  As others have noted, your application is attempting to use functionality that was not supported for IE6...hence the error.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer. As the combination of IIS-Header and document.createEvent() is non-recurring, I just moved the event in a try-catch-block, since it's not critical for the application.